# How to fix "on clicking a course an empty about page opens instead of the course outline"

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server, edx, openedx

I'm setting up an openedx platform on my server. Earlier the course outline would open on clicking the course but now it opens the about page displaying an error "there has been a 500 error on the platform server"

The course should open the course outline instead of the error containing about page

Comment: Please post this on another site such as https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Restart your LMS and CMS. or all. Then see, If not check logs.